# How to write transfer function?

Tags: matlab, transfer-function

I am an engineering student. I have some data stored in matlab. I need to build low pass filter to process my data. How can I write the transfer function? In my understanding transfer function is the output divided by input in laplace transform. But now I only have data, not function for input. My out put will also be data, if I use matlab built in function lowpass. How should I write the transfer function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to just make a lowpass filter for your stored data, you could use  [matlabs lowpass filter](https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/lowpass.html), or you can use the interface [interface](https://se.mathworks.com/discovery/filter-design.html)  built into matlab

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I want to use the matlab lowpass filter built in function, but how can I know its transfer function?

Comment: if defined, you can get the filter to return "b" and "a", this can be looked at as the transferfunction numinator and denominator: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#buagwwg-2